# If I embed SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 x64 in my application, can I deploy app on x86 clients?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am using x64 machine so if I embed SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 x64 in my app can I install that app on x86?

Comment: No, of course not. You can embed SQL Compact x86 and deploy that on both x64 and x86 though, or you can produce both x86 and x64 builds for each platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You would need to compile your app for x86 targets and include the x86 version of SQL Compact.

It's probably easier to just provide two different installers than a single one with both versions of your app and SQL Compact.

Comment: @ErikEJ: I never indicated it was required.  Simply that separating the two versions might be easier than packaging them up into a single installer.  However, your guide looked fairly easy. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can include all required files for both platforms as described here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Another choice, which trades a bit of space for a whole lot of simplicity is to deploy both the `x86/*` and `AMD64/*` native dlls alongside your managed `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` and let the runtime decide. It adds a few Mb, but streamlines you to a single build and single installer.